# Parsing JSON in swift inconsistent

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

I'm running into what I believe to be a bug. I have an array of objects returned from a server. However, when pulling values out of them I get inconsistent results. Each of these items are in the same array of the response from server:

When I try to pull the `quantity` value of this one it returns as in `Int`:

```
{
    address = "4040 MARKET ST RM 226";
    city = PHILADELPHIA;
    ln = "AMOXICILLIN 500 MG CAPSULE";
    ndc = 57237003105;
    npi = 1619912375;
    "pharmacy_name" = "GRACE PHARMACY INC";
    phone = "(215)895-5594";
    price = "8.00";
    quantity = 500;
    state = PA;
    vendor = una;
    zip = 19104;
}
```

However, when I try to pull `quantity` from this one, it's returned as a `String`.

```
{
    address = "1826 Chestnut St # 30";
    brand = G;
    city = Philadelphia;
    distance = "0.06";
    latitude = "39.951747";
    ln = "AMOXICILLIN 500 MG CAPSULE";
    longitude = "-75.171154";
    "ncpdp_id" = 3969485;
    ndc = 65862001705;
    "pharmacy_hours_of_operation" = "Open 24 Hours";
    "pharmacy_name" = "CVS PHARMACY";
    phone = "(215)972-0909";
    price = "11.82";
    quantity = 30;
    state = PA;
    vendor = scriptsave;
    zip = "19103-4902";
}
```

Why in the world would this be occurring? Both objects seems to be identical except for some extra values in one.

===

Serializing the JSON like this:

```
let searchResultsJSON: NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
```

Grabbing the values like this:

```
    quantity            = formDictionary["quantity"] as? Int
    quantityString      = formDictionary["quantity"] as? String
```

====

Here is the JSON:

```
results =     (
                {
            address = "4040 MARKET ST RM 226";
            city = PHILADELPHIA;
            ln = "ESOMEPRAZOLE MAG DR 40 MG CAP";
            ndc = 13668015510;
            npi = 1619912375;
            "pharmacy_name" = "GRACE PHARMACY INC";
            phone = "(215)895-5594";
            price = "74.00";
            quantity = 1000;
            state = PA;
            vendor = una;
            zip = 19104;
        },
{
            address = "1700 Market St";
            brand = G;
            city = Philadelphia;
            distance = "0.22";
            latitude = "39.952981";
            ln = "ESOMEPRAZOLE MAG DR 40 MG CAP";
            longitude = "-75.168431";
            "ncpdp_id" = 3985059;
            ndc = 00378235193;
            "pharmacy_hours_of_operation" = "S(Clsd) M(8a-6p) T(8a-6p) W(8a-6p) T(8a-6p) F(8a-6p) S(9a-12p)";
            "pharmacy_name" = "PICKWICK PHARMACY INC";
            phone = "(215)563-4860";
            price = "241.23";
            quantity = 30;
            state = PA;
            vendor = scriptsave;
            zip = "19103-3913";
        }
    );
```

So here, `quantity` in the first one is returned as an `Int` and as a `String` in the second one. I beginning to think this is a server side issue...

===

Looking at the JSON in Chrome does confirm that it's an encoding error from the server. Thanks @CouchDeveloper

[image]

Comment: What code are you using to get the quantity value?

Comment: What are you using to parse the JSON?

Comment: @TahTatsumoto I've updated my question. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: @Jeremiah I've updated my question. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: That could be if the server json-encodes `Int` values as `String` by default or uses different settings in different routines.

Comment: Well, in theory, each element in an JSON array could be different. You should also show the JSON.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper you need to see the entire JSON???

Comment: Just the relevant bits - not all. Especially, two or more elements whose "quantity" is a string in the first sample and a number in the second.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper updated, thanks for the help!

Comment: It would be event better, if you could post the JSON ( == a string, encoded in JSON). Your print seems to be a console log of the object representing the JSON.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper you're right. Looking at it like that confirms that the formatting is different.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's API's for JSONSerialization are a bit nasty for usage in Swift.
If your happy to make use of third-party frameworks, [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) will help with handling JSON in a type safe manner in swift. It's available as a Cocoapod, using Carthage or even Swift's own package manager.

You can then ensure you get non-nil Integer or String objects like so:

```
let name = json["name"].stringValue
let number = json["number"].intValue
```

Or you can handle non-existent values as optionals like so:

```
let name = json["name"].string
let number = json["number"].int
```

Comment: i'll give it a shot if I can't get anything else to work. I appreciate it!!